# Add a textfield dynamically with Jquery and Tapestry

Tags: jquery, html, textfield, tapestry

I need to display dynamically 10 textfields in .tml file so that the user can remove or add the required number. I found an example with Jquery and html form, the problem is that that I didn't manage to convert the code in Tapestry. Here is the [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-add-remove-textbox-dynamically-with-jquery/)
Can you please tell me if it is possible to use it with tapestry and if so help me to modify the code

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Tapestry 5 has a nice component for this called [AjaxFormLoop](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/AjaxFormLoop.html). Examples on how to use it can be found on the [JumpStart examples](http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/examples/ajax/formloop1) page.

I'm sure you can get the jquery code to work by utilizing the [tapestry5-jquery](https://github.com/got5/tapestry5-jquery) module. Though without any code or error messages it will be impossible to help you with your specific problem.

Comment: thanks for your answer it's exactly what I need but the example is too much complicated for me :p
Is there a simple example with just a label and a textfield ?

Comment: The other link I posted in the component reference on the tapestry website also has an example. But in the end it is not that complex. Don't be fooled by a bit of code :)